# When I refresh the one-page website, it doesn't show header first

Tags: javascript, html, css

So the problem is after refreshing the site, the header of the website is not displayed first. It leads me to the contact section (which is down lower) instead of header. Does anybody had the same problem and how to fix it? Note that I have one-page site which you only scroll up and down.

Comment: If I scroll to the bottom of the current page and refresh the browser keep my last position and doesn't scroll up either - Please create a [mcve]

Comment: This is what you call "HTML anchor links"...

Comment: I would love to see some code here. Can you show us the HTML and CSS please :)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems here. I don't know which it could be as you haven't given much information.

**Reason #1:** *HTML anchor links*

If your header has an ID for example `<h1 id="myinfo">Contact</h1>` and the URL is something like `example.com/index.html#myinfo` the browser is going to automatically scroll to the anchor of `myinfo`

**Reason #2:**

When you refresh almost any website, the browser will remember the previous position of the page you were at. If you were at the Contact section then refreshed the page. It will scroll back to that same position.

**Possible fix:**

If you want to force the page back to the top whether a refresh or anchor is used. Try placing this script just before the closing `BODY` tag or in the `HEAD` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload = function() {
    window.setTimeout(
        function() { window.scrollTo(0,0); },
        10
    );
};
</script>
```

The `window.setTimeout` is important as the page refreshes at the top then scrolls away. We need to delay the function so we scroll after the browser does.

Hope this helps in some way.

EDIT: 2018/Nov/16

The only catch here is if you need HTML anchor links to jump to different places on the page. Anchor links will be completely ignored.

If you disable JavaScript, our code won't work at all. You could use the script above to hide the page before the content loads then show it after the page has loaded but that will lead to the page been white for a second. Google use to do this a few years ago so no one could see the elements on the page loading.

This script need to be place after the `BODY` tag but before the main content. It won't work if it's in the `HEAD`.

```
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

    document.body.style.display = "none";

    // If onbeforeunload fails
    window.onload = function() {
        window.setTimeout(
            function() {
                window.scrollTo(0,0);
                document.body.style.display = "inherit";
            },
            0
        );
    };

    /* This should scroll the page to the top before the page refreshes */
    window.onbeforeunload = function() { window.scrollTo(0,0); }

    //-->
    </script>

    . . . { Your content here } . . .
```

If JavaScript is disabled this solution won't work. Some people do have JavaScript disabled.

There is no other way to force the page up to the top, sorry.

Comment: I have to tell you great thanks because this completely worked out! It's great!I have one question more about this. When I do refresh, there is still an issue that my contact section appears first but very shortly (like one-second-blink), and than it goes on the top of the website. Is there any solution to prevent this issue? I tried to put shorter time (you put 10, I tried 1) but it's still happening. What is the catch?

Comment: Hi Vlada, Unfortunately, on a slow device or a very slow loading web page you are going to see that "one-second-blink". There's nothing much you can do about that, sorry. You could try setting the timer to 0 but the same thing may again happen. The browser is automatically scrolling and we are telling it to go back up after it has scrolled. 16ms is enough not to notice a blink on a 60fps device, the short delay of 10ms prevents the browser scrolling happening after the timer. If the page takes ~200ms to load, the script won't excute until ~210ms which is why there's a blink.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and answers! It is like I supposed... Maybe I could later do audit to my site and speed it up a bit? Probably it will stop blink effect?

Comment: That could help but it may also be best to hide the body then show everything after the page has loaded and scrolled to the top as that won't give a blink affect as in my last example. You'd need the page to load in less than 16 milliseconds. speed may work for you but not for someone else viewing the page.

Comment: I'm not sure if the following code will work for you but it's worth a try I've also updated the answer to reflect this: window.onbeforeunload = function() { window.scrollTo(0,0); } // This should reset the scroll position before the page refreshes regardsless of anchors or browser cache.

Comment: Hm... didn't work this code. But you've already helped me a lot! Thank you! If you have some time, maybe you could check another question of mine. I have problem to make fixed position of an item on my site... It gave me a real headache! LOL! The topic is called "Go-to-top button completely disappears on scroll". I described a problem there but if you need extra info, feel free to ask me! I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score -1):

I was seen the same problem, Now I got the root cause of this problem

**Reason:**

if you use `autofocus` in the single page web, then this problem will accrue, this will automatically focus on the file when you reload

```
<input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" name="name" required autofocus>
```

**Problem Fix**
just remove `autofocus` from your form

```
<input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" name="name" required>
```